# Can I add a mouse click callback to decorated text?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a decoration applied to the portion of text (matched with regex) it has the option to specify a `hoverMessage` I'm wondering if there is a way to specify a mouse click to this element. I would like to execute some function based on which decorated text user clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find any solution for mouse click. It was mentioned in [other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49679711/923340) question that exposing mouse events is an unlikely addition to the API :(

What I was able to do is:

- Add contribute points:

  - commands
  - menus

    - editor/context
    - commandPalette
- register the command in js and get the location from the `textEditor`

In `package.json` I'm setting my command so it is displayed in a context menu only with provided `title`, when file opened is a `.log` file.

```
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "gd.my-ext.myCommand",
        "title": "My Command"
      }
    ],
    "menus": {
      "commandPalette": [
        {
          "command": "gd.me-ext.myCommand",
          "when": "false"
        }
      ],
      "editor/context": [
        {
          "command": "gd.me-ext.myCommand",
          "group": "navigation",
          "when": "resourceExtname == .log"
        },
      ]
    },
```

Then in `extension.ts` I'm registering a text editor command and using `textEditor`'s `selection` and `document`.

```
const disposable = vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand(
    'gd.me-ext.myCommand',
    (textEditor, edit, ...rest): void => {
      const { selection, document } = textEditor;
      console.log(selection.start.line);
      const line: vscode.TextLine = document.lineAt(selection.start.line);
      // The selection will tell me where the cursor is and I can find a line
      // in which I can use the regex I've used to apply decoration and compare if it was selection I wanted :)
    }
  );
  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
```